# Gamepad mapping in Hurrican game

Tags: kubuntu, games, flatpak, gamepad

I tried to install the old but fantastic Hurrican game (developed by Poke 53280) on Kubuntu 22.04 via flatpak (https://holarse.de/wiki/hurrican). The game seems to run fine but I'm unable to configure my game pad (I tried two completely different pads) in a usable way.

I could select all my desired mappings just fine. This includes using the right trigger button (displayed as button 8 in the game settings) as fire button (this mapping is important for me).

The configuration works completely. However whenever I press the selected fire button the game exits to the main menu like when pressing the escape button. It appears to me that the trigger button now has two functions: Fire (as selected by myself) and some pause/exit/escape function (I could not find a way to modify this function).

Any ideas?

Comment: does the game support gamepads?

Comment: Yes. In the control configuration menu there is an entry to select input device and when selecting my pad it explicitly allows selecting between Joystick and Joypad.